# Differences among commands in coloring node labels in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wonder if there are fundamental differences among the following label coloring procedures in `TiKZ` (aside from defining a style as mentioned in the manual) since they seem to produce the same effect, or is it just a matter of coding style?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (m1) at (0,0) (0,-2mm) [label={[red]right:$A$}]{First method}; %
\node (m2) [below=of m1] [label=right:\textcolor{red}{$A$}]{Second method};
\node (m3) [below=of m2] [label=right:{\color{red}$A$}]{Third method};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The last two belong to [`xcolor`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/xcolor) package. From its manual:

- `\color{<color>}[<model-list>]{<spec-list>}` Switches to the color given either by name/expression or by model/specification. This color will stay in effect until the end of the current TeX group.
- `\textcolor{<color>}{<text>}[<model-list>]{<spec-list>}{<text>}` are just alternative syntax for `\color`, in which the groups are added implicitly. Thus `<text>` appears in the specified color, but then the color reverts to its previous value. Additionally, it calls `\leavevmode` to ensure the start of horizontal mode.

The first one is TikZ related and it recognizes the color name. Then, sets

```
fill=red,draw=red,text=red
```

This command doesn't operate on the text inside the box and lets the regular mechanism work for the color change. Others operate directly inside the node text box.

Example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[blue] (a) {\color{red}This should be blue};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

To see the differences, look at this modified example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (m1) [label={[red]right:@$A$B}]{First method}; %
\node (m2) [below=of m1] [label=right:@\textcolor{red}{$A$}B]{Second method};
\node (m3) [below=of m2] [label=right:{@\color{red}$A$B}]{Third method};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With first method, the whole text is red.

With second method, it's just `$A$`.

With third method, the text is red from the call to `\color` to the end of the label (or another call to `\color`).